# How to "glue in" a lambda inside another lambda body?

Tags: ruby, lambda

Say I have such two lambdas in Ruby:

```
lambda1 = -> { puts 'lambda1' }
lambda2 = -> {
  puts 'lambda2 calls lambda1'
  lambda1.()
}
```

It works as expected:

```
lambda1.()
# lambda1
lambda2.()
# lambda2 calls lambda1
# lambda1
```

But now if I remove `lambda1`, `lambda2` will stop working:

```
lambda1 = nil
lambda2.()
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass

What can I do to "glue in" my `lambda1` to `lambda2` to make the first an inherent part of the second and avoid that situation?

Comment: can you provide real world usage? this contrived exampled does not give enough context and I don't see what you're trying to get. It is unclear, what you are asking and what is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `lambda2` captures the variable `lambda1` in a closure, so it notices when `lambda1` changes later on. The solution is just to make it capture a different variable:

```
lambda1 = -> { puts 'lambda1' }
x = lambda1 # copy the reference
lambda2 = -> { x.() }
lambda1 = nil
lambda2.()
```

"But this has the same problem!" you might say, "I can break it by reassigning `x`!" Well then make it so `x` is protected by the scope:

```
def wrap x
  -> { x.() }
end

lambda1 = -> { puts 'lambda1' }
lambda2 = wrap lambda1
lambda1 = nil
lambda2.()
```